# Pagination via get variables?

Tags: pagination, get

I'm trying to use GET variables to apply pagination to a channel entries request (so can access via URL/AJAX).

Is there a variable that would work, eg ?P=10 or ?page=10

Tried offset but obviously that just reduces the number of entries available to query against.

Comment: Why are you using GET? Could this not be done with the 'standard' EE pagination URL?

Answer (score 1):

Just use the standard pagination with AJAX. /P10 etc. works fine.